# play action composition delegate to separate call

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, action

I am trying to use action composition in play to check the logged in user in each class methods, I can't find out how I can redirect the user to login screen if no session is present,

this is my verboseaction.java

```
public class VerboseAction extends play.mvc.Action.Simple {

    private static final play.Logger.ALogger log = play.Logger.of(VerboseAction.class);
    public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        if(ctx.session().get("userEmail")!="" && ctx.session().get("userEmail")!=null)
            return redirect(routes.UserSession.index());
        else
            return delegate.call(ctx);
    }
}
```

the error I'm getting is

`error: incompatible types: Result cannot be converted to Promise<Result>`

because redirect is a `Result` type

how can I fix this,

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

got it working with

`return F.Promise.pure(redirect("/index"));`

thanks to [this link](http://rijware.com/securing-a-play-framework-site-with-https-redirects/)